# VirtualBox and Ubuntu 14.04 why so slow?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

The host system is an iMAC:

```
    macOS Mojave
    Version 10.14.5
    iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015)
    Processor 4 GHz Intel Core i7
    Memory 16 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
    Graphics AMD Radeon R9 M395X 4 GB
```

VirtualBox:

```
    Version: 6.08 r130520 (Qt5.6.3)
    VirtualBox 6.0.8 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack
```

The VM is painfully slow, when I click on the desktop in the VM I have several seconds before I see a response.  Is there anything I can do to improve the performance.  The host system is super quick.

[Edit] Settings have changed as a result of various suggestions from the VirtualBox community:

```
    Base Memory:  4096 MB
    Chipset: PIIX3
    Extended Features: Enable I/O APIC
                       Hardware Clock in UTC time
    Processor(s): 4
    Execution Cap: 100%
    Video Memory: 128MB
    Graphics Controller: VBoxVGA
    Acceleration: Enable 3D Acceleration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is what I did, just changing the settings and it does seemed to have improved performance:

```
Base Memory:  4096 MB
Chipset: PIIX3
Extended Features: Enable I/O APIC
                   Hardware Clock in UTC time
Processor(s): 4
Execution Cap: 100%
Video Memory: 128MB
Graphics Controller: VBoxVGA
Acceleration: Enable 3D Acceleration
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on a MacBook Pro with Retina display. Performance was fine when I moved the VM window to a non-Retina display, but really slow when showing on a Retina display.

Check your machine settings under **Settings > Display > Graphics Controller**. Mine was originally set to VBoxVGA. Setting this to **VMSVGA** improved graphics performance greatly. Also **enable 3D acceleration**, this seems to improve performance for me as well; forces it to use the discrete graphics card though, so it may decrease battery life.

Comment: Thank you, I'll edit to post my settings now, its much better now.

Comment: Great! I suggest you post your findings as another answer to your own question (rather than embedding it in your question). Do you know which of those settings did the trick for you?